# How to use class static method or custom function in template?

Tags: angular

My class is like this:

```
export class Image {
  static getUrl(x: Image) {
      return CONFIG.host + x.url
  }

  constructor(private url: string, public alt: string) {}
}
```

My template is like:

```
<img [src]="Image.getUrl(image)" [alt]="image.alt" >
```

My component is like:

```
export class MyComponent {
  image: Image;
  Image = Image;
}
```

For the moment I have to pass the class itself `Image` manually to the component, in order by use `Image.getUrl`. What's a standard way to use a custom function or class method in a template?

If I use instance methods, then if I receive a Json that contains a property looks like `Image`, I have to do a proper type cast before calling the method, which is not very convenient if it is in a nested json.

Comment: Why does the method definition need to be like that? It makes a lot more sense just to make it an instance method with no parameters, and just call the method on the instance, using the instance url.

Comment: You could also just do `get url() {   }`. That way you can just access it like a regular property. `image.url`

Comment: @peeskillet Because if I add instance method it is no longer compatible with json like objects automatically.

Comment: @colinfang I want to do that too... I end up with the same Image=Image workaround.. :(

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to refer to global variables/classes inside template. The scope of template is within its hosting Component.

Either you make it non-static getter of the `Image` class or define a custom pipe to help you with transforming `Image` to `imageUrl`.